# change current page with liferay

Tags: liferay

how can i change the current page with liferay, i use `themedisplay` api. but i didn't find how can i change the current page from  `web/guest/new` to  `/web/guest/new22`. i use the bellow code to get current url

```
 String currentCompleteURL = PortalUtil.getCurrentURL(rdReq);
 ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) rdReq.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
 String title = themeDisplay.getLayout().getName(themeDisplay.getLocale());
 System.out.println("title    "+title);
```

Comment: Need more details as to what you are trying to do? Are you trying to redirect user to a different landing page on login?

Comment: i want to navigate from web/guest/new to /web/guest/new22

Comment: You mean to say when user clicks on /web/guest/new, he should be automatically redirected to /web/guest/new22?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to redirect all the request to a particular page(in your case /web/guest/new) to somewhere else(in your case /web/guest/new22), what you can do is go to Manage Page from /web/guest/new page and then select **Link to Page** from **Type** drop down. This will show another drop down named "Link to Page" below **Type** from where you can select the page you want to redirect the user to(web/guest/new22).